# Does version MySQl 5.6.24 not support the none object orientated code of previous versions?

Tags: mysql, php, mysql-5.6

I have the following code that works fine in other versions of Mysql but not in 5.6.24. Its on a testing server and not live. It works fine on the on-line server, which uses a version lower.

```
5. $con = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "", "databasename");
6.if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
7.    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
8.}
9. echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
```

Line numbers inserted just to show the relationship to the error message.

The user is set up with full privileges for the database in question.
When I try to make the connection I get the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\635csi\connections\newcon.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\635csi\connections\newcon.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\635csi\connections\newcon.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\635csi\connections\newcon.php on line 9

Question
Does version MySQL 5.6.24  not support the none object orientated code of previous versions?

Strangely enough it makes the connection and the site works - but shows the error messages.

Comment: This is probably a PHP issue, not mysql.

Comment: You're assigning the new connection to `$con`, then trying to call methods on `$mysqli`. Change one or the other.